# Github wiki in showing old versions

Tags: github, accessibility, version, wiki

Is there a way to view old historic revisions of wiki on github?

[Here](https://github.community/t/accessing-old-wiki-revisions-markdown-source/1358) it says,

> You can access the old rendered version, but not the source

But I found I can access neither the old rendered version, nor the source via github web.

**UPDATE/Conclusion:**

Thanks to VonC's answer, it turns out that GH might have disabled such feature in new repo/wiki --

- This is a wiki history from one of my old repo
  [image]
- This is a wiki history from my brand new repo created several days ago
  [image]
  The mouse is over SHA-1 hash but there is no link there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki documentation has a "[Viewing previous content](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/viewing-a-wikis-history-of-changes#viewing-previous-content)" section:

> On the wiki history table, you can click a [SHA-1 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) (the sequence of letters and numbers to the far right) to see a wiki page as it existed at a particular point in time.
>
> [image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/wiki/wiki_sha_number.png]

This is after clicking on the [revisions of a wiki page](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/viewing-a-wikis-history-of-changes#viewing-wiki-history).

So you can access past rendered content that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it turns out that GH might have disabled such feature in new repo/wiki. See my updated OP.

Comment: @xpt Does the wiki page of your new wiki has multiple revision (did you modify it at least once, or twice)?

Comment: Yes, VonC, see the screenshot in my OP, and you can try creating a brand new repo and write multiple revision wiki yourself as well.

Comment: @xpt I just did, and... it works: https://github.com/VonC/gitw/wiki/Home/_history: I can see the content of the page in both revisions.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! Just found that somehow my above shown multiple-changes have been reduce to one single version, and my saved version comparison url is now 404. Weird. Anyway, now I know where to check. Thanks for your help and all the followups! Ah! found it -- I changed the title, and all the historic changed version will be gone after that.